# Why when using forward slash in SQLdeveloper the pl/sql script is hanging?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Using forward slash in SQLdeveloper is working fine on one machine but in another machine (and different DB) the pl/sql script is hanging, meaning the procedure (ends with '/') is running without stopping.

For some reason it also happens in SQL*Plus which usually is ok with '/'.
Once we are removing the '/' the issue is resolved.

what can cause it?

Comment: By 'resolved' you mean the PL/SQL block no longer runs at all? Sounds like the block is just taking a long time to execute - either because you've introduced an infinite loop (e.g. with a break condition that is met on the other DB, but not on this one), or something is blocking, or it is just a genuinely long-running query or operation. But without seeing what you're doing we can't really guess what's wrong.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. when we remove the '/' it runs fine on both tools. it's a simple 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW' block, in other environment it took a second.

Comment: be careful with '/' - in sqlplus it means simply, run what i put in the buffer, AGAIN - in sqldev it's used exclusively to mark the end of plsql code blocks

Comment: If it's a simple static `create or replace view` statement then it isn't PL/SQL. And if that is hanging then something internal might be blocking - could be something nasty, could be a DDL trigger trying to record the action, etc. So you should probably talk to your DBA to see if they can see what's happening.

Comment: unfortunately it is someone from our client side and we have no way to see exactly what is there and only specific requests from our side can be sent to check specific configuration, the DBA we are talking with said there were no locks but don't think he checked anything else.

Comment: I think it might be SQLTERMINATOR issue, but can't find how do i check the current state of it? 'show" didn't work ...